# HttpClient exception in Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, http, httpclient

I am using HttpClient to send and receive data from the server in my Windows 8 app.

Below is my code:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic;
handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, URL);

request.Content = new StreamContent(new System.IO.MemoryStream(_postDataInBytes));
request.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

Now the problem is that I get an exception at SendAsync() function. The exception is **"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive"**.
This occurs randomly. Can anybody please tell me what is the problem here?

Comment: Can you try with setting the request's KeepAlive to true ? Check this link for some explanation on HTTP 1.0 vs 1.1 and KeepAlive : http://geekswithblogs.net/Denis/archive/2005/08/16/50365.aspx

Comment: Take a look at this KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/915599

Comment: How to set KeepAlive and MaxServicePointIdleTime in HttpClient object?

Comment: My comment about HTTP 1.1 and Keep Alive may not be an issue for you because for HttpRequestMessage the version property is set to 1.1 by default and the and when using HTTP/1.1 the KeepAlive header is true by default. You should have persistent connections ideally.

Comment: Could it be an issue with Proxy?

Comment: It looks like the issue is related to proxy. We have proxy enabled in our network. I tried disabling proxy for our domain in IE and set UseProxy property to False in HttpClient, it never threw an exception. Can you please tell me how to handle proxy using HttpClient?

Comment: Check this answer, it may have some useful information for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228324/new-httpclient-proxy-settings-issues