# C# How to set HttpClient Keep-Alive to false

Tags: c#, .net, rest, httpclient, httpwebresponse

I had a low performance problem with HTTP requests on .NET. The HTTP GET request to a REST API on the localhost took about 500 ms to complete. I spent a lot of time to fix it. I have tried many ways: `HttpClient`, `HttpWebRequest`, `WebClient` and `RestSharp`. None of them work. Most solutions on the Internet said to set `Proxy` parameter to `null` but it still won't work faster.

The only way I found to reduce this time is to set the Keep-Alive parameter of request to false:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "GET";
request.KeepAlive = false;

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

This works great. Time is reduced to 7-10 ms. But now in some reasons I need to use `HttpClient` instead of `HttpWebRequest`. And I can't find how to set Keep-Alive to false for `HttpClient`. The only thing I found is how to set it to true by setting a "connection" header to "Keep-Alive".

I am using this code for POST request by HttpClient:

```
HttpClient _http = new HttpClient();
_http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
_http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
_http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Keep-Alive", "timeout=600");

var content = new StringContent(
request, Encoding.UTF8, "application/%appname%+xml");
content.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(
    new NameValueHeaderValue("type", "payload")
);

HttpResponseMessage response = await _http.PostAsync(uri, content);
```

And it still takes about 500-600 ms to complete.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211812/using-a-keep-alive-connection-in-winrts-httpclient-class ... just an idea ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Thanks, this is a first link in the Google search result. I've already tried this:
content.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive", "false");
But this takes more than 500 ms to complete too.

Comment: This discussion also: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30104

Answer (score 51):

Use this code to disable HTTP Keep-Alive on the client:

```
_http.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
```

This will set `Connection` request header to `close`.

Answer (score 41):

When you set `HttpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true` the header set is **Connection: keep-alive**

When you set `HttpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false` the header set is **Connection: close**

So you will need

```
_http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "close");
```

Answer (score 5):

See code below:

```
HttpClient cli;
...
cli.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
cli.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Keep-Alive", "600");
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I've updated a question with my code.

Comment: The sample you posted that "works great" is the equivalent of KeepAlive=False. The header you state you tried is the equivalent of KeepAlive=True. You are doing the opposite of what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help you, I have tested

```
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.Add("Keep-Alive");
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote HttpClientHandler, and in the handler just before the request I deleted the header "Connection". In this case, it sets the default "Connection: keep-alive". Even if before that you put it in the HttpClient by default, set properties, etc. Check your handlers.