# WebRequest class and set keepAlive to false

Tags: c#, webrequest, keep-alive

I'm using the [WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?view=netcore-3.1) class to make calls to a web service.

I want to set the KeepAlive property to 'false' but i'm not finding this attribute.

How can I do it?

Comment: `KeepAlive` is a property that belongs to [HttpWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest), the class object generated when a new WebRequest is created: `HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(URI);`. `KeepAlive` is usually set to `true` in Http 1.1 and is ignored in Http 2.0, since it's the default and you cannot change it. Http 1.0 (if you can find something that uses it somewhere), can be set to `false` (then, it depends on you what happens). If you set `KeepAlive = false`, it can be interpreted as `ConnectionClose`.

Comment: Btw, you don't *create* a connection, you ask for one, it's the `ServicePoint` assigned to your connection request that handles this. `KeepAlive` is also part of the transaction performed in the handshake. Why do you think you need to set `KeepAlive = false`?

Answer (score 1):

As Microsoft has mentioned. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?view=netcore-3.1)

> We advise not to use WebRequest or its derivative classes for the new development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.Http.HttpClientclass.

WebRequest is the basic abstract class for. NET request/response model to access data from the Internet. So you can use **HttpClient** instead that has `KeepAlive` property.

[C# How to set HttpClient Keep-Alive to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357943/c-sharp-how-to-set-httpclient-keep-alive-to-false)
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: This is helpful, although the quoted documentation of unknown source is confusing: first "We advise ... to use WebRequest" but then "Instead, use ... HttpClient".  It seems like that first sentence is missing "_not_ to use".  The [English documentation for `WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest) reads "We don't recommend that you use WebRequest or its derived classes for new development." and translating the French version I get "We do not recommend using WebRequest or its derived classes for new development."

Comment: **Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class.** that's why i said use `httpClient`

Comment: yeah the statement is translated and i copied. from OPs linked source.

Comment: Right, but you see that the first sentence is saying "to use" — not "not to use" — `WebRequest`?  The first sentence says "use WebRequest" and then the second says "use ... HttpClient."  That's why I said it's confusing.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I want to know if there is a solution if we want to keep using WebRequest class.

Comment: @marcus i don't think so. You'll need to use implementation of it that is `httpWebRequest`

Comment: You could access the respective headers via `request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Connection]` and `request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.KeepAlive]`, although [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.webheadercollection) says that the `Connection` header is "restricted".  How are you using `WebRequest`, though?  It's an abstract class, so ultimately you have to be using something that's a derived class.  Maybe you're already using `HttpWebRequest` and just need to cast it?  That class exposes proper `Connection` and `KeepAlive` properties.