# How to Handle the Response When Sending a PING to API WebSocket

Tags: c#, json, http, binance

I have this API (Binance API) in which I can subscribe to data stream in order to get instant update for that given data.

https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#user-data-streams

As per the documentation above, it says that we need first to create a `listenkey` and then use this `listenkey` to get data streams. Now every 60 minutes the `listenkey` will expire unless we push a PING to the server to keep the `listenkey` alive.

```
string Uri = Url + "/api/v3/userDataStream?";
string Parameters = $"listenKey={UserDataListenKey}";
var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.Headers.Add("X-MBX-APIKEY", ApiKey);
request.RequestUri = new Uri(Uri + Parameters);
request.Method = HttpMethod.Put;
var client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage msg = await client.SendAsync(request);
var res = await msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
WriteToTerminal(res);
```

[image]

Now after I send the PING I'll update the `listenkey` and set the timer for another PING in 30 min.
The thing is that the response is not clear that if the `listenkey` was updated or not, as I only get an empty JSON string. Also, in the documentation they are not mentioning anything on how handle the returned response.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use Keep-Alive which will send a datagram with no data so connection does not close.  Add the header keep-Alive. See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357943/c-sharp-how-to-set-httpclient-keep-alive-to-false

Comment: What is the status code that you get back? I would guess that as long as it's a 2xx code then everything is okay.

Comment: @IanBoggs I run the method HttpResponseMessage.StatusCode and it returned an OK. Is this the same as 200 code?

Comment: Yes, 200 is OK.

Answer (score 0):

"Now every 60 minutes the listenkey will expire unless we push a PING to the server to keep the listenkey alive."  This is not correct.

You should do: "Doing a PUT on a listenKey will extend its validity for 60 minutes."  by this endpoint `PUT /api/v3/userDataStream`, please check the document for details.